# How to add more palette in the Image Trace's Colors options?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-trace, live-trace

My goal is to `Image Trace` an image and recolor it with specific sets of color by the **AI**.

The problem are:

1. I don't know how to edit the `Document library`.
2. I need to compare between 3 artboards (4/8/12 color).

The solution that I know:

1. [Click the Expand button and manually change the color one by one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21562/adobe-illustrator-is-there-a-way-to-set-the-image-trace-palette-limit-to-a-numb)

Comment: It seems reasonable. Illustrator is after all a do it manually kind of tool.

Comment: @joojaa so do you know how to add more palette to the `Document library` option in the `Image Trace` feature?

Comment: No i was pointing out that illustrator is a manual tool so doing things manually is what its for. All of the automation that illustrator has is coincidental, you can not rely on it to solve all your problems. The automatic tools arent designed with open automation in mind. But read the linked answer.